# How can I get .innerHTML to write a working script

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, embed, innerhtml

I am attempting to create a test web page that will hold two div containers, one on the left at 45% width, and one on the right at 45% width. The one on the left will have a matrix of logos corresponding to various twitter feeds that I want to dynamically embed in a container on the right hand side of the page. This meaning that if I were to click on the "Google" thumbnail on the matrix of logos on the left hand side, then the empty container on the right hand side will instantly run through a script, and embed a twitter feed with respect to that twitter handle **"@Google"**

```
<div id="lefthand-container">
    <center>
        <!--------------------Feed #1--------------->
        <a href="#"><img src="/images/googleicon.png" class="grow" width="150" 
           title="Google" alt="Google" border="5" 
           style="box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #888888;" onclick="FeedInduce_Google()"></a>
        <!--...--->
    </center>
</div>
<!---------------------End List of Feeds-------------------->

<div id="righthand-container">
        <h1>This should get replaced with the feed information of the image you click</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function FeedInduce_Google()
        {document.getElementById("righthand-container").innerHTML = GoogleFeed;}
            // ...
            GoogleFeed =    '<center>';
            GoogleFeed +=   '<img src="http://patrickcoombe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/new-google-logo-2015.png" width="450" alt="Google"><br/>';
            GoogleFeed +=   '<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/google" target="_blank">Tweets by @Google</a><br/>';
            GoogleFeed +=   '<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?"http":"https";if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script><br/>';
```

Unfortunately, every time that I click on the Google thumbnail, it will only load up what seems to be the first three lines of the variable "GoogleFeed"

I would've used image syntax but I need "10 reputations", sorry!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m97A0.png

And I did reference the Twitter embed set-up script as instructed, it is the first script run as the body loads, right below the open body tag

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        t = window.twttr || {};
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

        t._e = [];
        t.ready = function(f) {
            t._e.push(f);
        };
            return t;
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
    </script>
```

If you look at the picture hard enough though, it looks as though there is a small space under the Twitter redirect handle is innerHTML'd in, so that indicates to me that the javascript is actually posting something there, but the script will not seem to create the widget feed that I want.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this method is not working for dynamically embedding twitter feeds via **document.innerHTML**?

Comment: The browser ignores `<script>` tags when you add them via `.innerHTML`.

Comment: I had a feeling that it was doing that. Is there a work-around for this? Maybe it might be beneficial to create a <script id="PASTEHERE"></script> and innerHTML that last line into that tag? I'm not really sure the best approach for this haha